# Opaque Type C-pointer to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers

I came across the following situation.*(Update: Known as **Opaque Type**; Thanks for info @iharob)*

Type P is `typedef`-ed in public_api.h along with some functions that create, modify and destroy it, eg. `createP` in following snippet.

However, its implementation is based on an hidden type. Hidden, because it is defined in the source that is generally available as compiled binary, ready to be installed. Every such operation relies on pointer type casting.

My use case is simplified as under:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

/* defined in **public** api */
// _PUB_API_ {{{
typedef struct P P;
P* createP();
// }}} _PUB_API_

/* defined in **implementation** files, that are compiled to binary */
// HID_IMPL {{{
typedef struct P_ P_;
struct P_ {};

P* createP() { return (P*) new P_(); }
// }}} HID_IMPL

/* **Use case** */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  P* p = createP();

  if (p == NULL)
  { /* does not execute */
    cerr << "Unable to create P" << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  typedef boost::shared_ptr<P> PpointerT;
  //typedef boost::scoped_ptr<P> PpointerT;
  PpointerT ptr = PpointerT(createP(), &deleteP); // compilation error

  if (!ptr)
  {
    cerr << "Error creating shared pointer PpointerT" << '\n';
    return 2;
  }

  cerr << "P created!" << '\n'
       << "PpointerT created!" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I want to use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. Here, I am stranded. Because, the smart pointers require the type to be complete at the time of instantiation (implemented in boost with `checked_delete.hpp`)

1. I might have to create a wrapper class around type P (perhaps every such type) that takes care of create, modify and destroy functions rationally, with the constructor, the member functions, and the destructor. **Is it worth the trouble rather than going ahead with raw pointers?**
2. **Is there any other way to work around this limitation imposed by the library?**

**Update:**

The situation above does have a solution with the shared_ptr library, as shown in the answer, by @Richard. Summarizingly, the constructor required a deleter class, that acts as a destroying functor for the `OpaqueType*`, for example:

```
// Update:PUB_API
void deleteP(P* p);

// Update:HID_IMPL
void deleteP(P* p) { delete (P*) p; } // I don't know if type casting
                                      // here is necessary?

PpointerT ptr = Ppointer(createP(), &deleteP);
```

Then the whole program runs fine. And indeed satisfies the use case.

Comment: The term you want is **opaque** -> *is based on an hidden type*

Comment: Since smart pointers need to be able to create and delete objects, the declaration of the constructor and destructor of the templated type need to be visible

Comment: @iharob Thanks for the terminology I will use it and update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to do provided the library also exports a function to destroy the opaque type. You can then use this function in the *custom deleter* of your smart pointer.

I have used `std::` smart pointers here, but the principles hold in `boost` also.

example:

```
// included from library:

struct Foo;
Foo* make_foo();
void destroy_foo(const Foo*);


// your code:

auto my_foo_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(make_foo(), &destroy_foo);


// or unique_ptr:

auto unique_foo = std::unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(const Foo*)>(make_foo(),
                                                            &destroy_foo);
```

Comment: Thanks @Richards --- It works like a charm. I should have at least fiddled with the library once to figure it out. The library does provide a deleter, and I have edited the code above. Thanks again.

Comment: @bvraghav great. The custom deleters are often overlooked :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the library, you can create a wrapper class that allocates the pointer in it's constructor and deallocates it in it's destructor with a cast operator defined to have access to the pointer easily by just casting. It's what a scoped pointer does and it's fairly simple to implement.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class ScopedCharPointer
{
public:
    ScopedCharPointer(size_t size);
    ~ScopedCharPointer();
    operator char *();
private:
    char *pointer;
};

ScopedCharPointer::ScopedCharPointer(size_t size) :
    pointer(new char[size])
{
}

ScopedCharPointer::~ScopedCharPointer()
{
    delete[] pointer;
}

ScopedCharPointer::operator char *()
{
    return pointer;
}

int
main(void)
{
    ScopedCharPointer example(100);
    char *pointer = static_cast<char *>(example);
    std::cout << static_cast<void *>(pointer) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much close to what I felt, when I suggested pt. 1

Thanks a ton for implementation.

Practically, if I go this far, I would prefer to declare all the functions that accept `OpaqueType*` as the first argument over as public member to `OpaqueWrapperType`, and not have the pointer implementation at all. But that is me, and not everyone.